# How can I create a loader for webpack which exposes all sources via a function?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to have a loader that *collects* all `css` sources and allows me to get all contents in a function. Like this:

Webpack config

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'my-loader'}
  ]
}
```

JS file A (`foo.js`)

```
import './foo.css';
```

JS file B (`bar.js`)

```
import './bar.css';
```

JS file C (`app.js`)

```
import './app.css';
import getAllCSSContents from 'my-loader';

const css = getAllCSSContents();
```

where `getAllCSSContents` would return all CSS contents from `foo.css`, `bar.css` and `app.css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because the loader you want to make needs to know about all CSS modules before it can generate the code it needs to return, making it stateful (loaders are meant to be pure functions that transform one input module).

You can kind of achieve what you want using [`raw-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader) and [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-context) like this:

```js
// Load all CSS files in the current directory and descendants
const context = require.context('!raw-loader!./', true, /\.css$/);
const cssFiles = {};

for (let filename of context.keys()) {
  cssFiles[filename] = context(filename);
}
```